# scala type requires toString

Tags: scala, tostring, type-bounds

In Scala, what's the most generalizable way to require a type can be treated as a String?

I know view bound requires that an object can be "viewed as" another type, but this doesn't work.

```
def func[T <% String](s: T): String = s.toString

val x: Long = 0

x.toString // String = 0
func(x)    // error: No implicit view available from Long => String.
```

Type Any has a toString method...  so I could just do a type bound...  but is every object in Scala automatically a subtype of Any?  It seems like maybe, but is this dumb for some reason I'm not anticipating?

```
def func[T <: Any](s: T): String = s.toString

class A { override def toString "xxx" }
func(new A) // String = xxx

class B(val b: Int) 
func(new B(0)) // String = B@12345678

object C { override def toString = "ccc" }
func(C) // String = ccc
```

So it seems to work, even though my objects don't explicitly extend any subclass of Any.  Will this generalize to any object in Scala, even if it doesn't necessarily end up with a pretty string that looks like what I want?

**EDIT**

per comment below, viewing as a string and creating a new string are different.  in this case, I don't care, but to make the view bound version work...  I'd guess something like this would be appropriate?

```
implicit def strConv[T](s: T) = s.toString

def func[T <% String](s: T) = s

func(new A) // A = xxx
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with the wrapper here?  Why not just *call* `s.toString`?

Comment: To be clear here, your change doesn't do the same thing that the original function tried to do.  You're not viewing your parameter as a string, you're just creating a new string based on it, and then operating on that string.

Comment: good clarification @IanMcLaird, thanks.  editing question.  I don't care in this instance, but I would like to understand the difference.

Comment: I'll post an answer to discuss that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it will always work: `Any` is the highest thing in the hierarchy. Check out the [diagram](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/images/classhierarchy.png). Looks like it generalizes Scala's value types (`AnyVal`) and reference types (`AnyRef`). As a consequence, `T <: Any` will be true for any `T`.

With that in mind, you can drop `T <: Any` completely (and replace it with just `T`). Heck, the REPL even simplifies it for you:

```
scala> def func[T <: Any](s: T): String = s.toString
func: [T](s: T)String
```

#### EDIT

In case it isn't clear - you might as well just use `.toString` straight up - this function will serve no purpose.

Comment: Of course, if *that's* what you want, you might as well just call `s.toString`.  There's really no reason for this wrapper.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Yeah. I guess I should make that clearer.

Comment: I suspect that this is an X/Y problem.  I suspect that the OP has something else in mind, and he's asking about his solution to his actual problem.

Comment: great info, thanks @Alec!  ha...  actual function has a bit more to it than example.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your edit and what those view bounds are for.

A view bound exists to allow you to have a function that will accept any type so long as an implicit conversion exists to the type you *wish* you had.  I'm going to make your sample function just a touch fancier in the interests of showing what that really means.

First, some implicit conversions (I'm going to stick with `Long` and `Double` to drive the point home)

```
implicit def long2String(l: Long) = l.toString
implicit def double2String(d: Double) = d.toString
```

Now, a function that really wants to operate on `Strings`, but will accept anything that's convertible to `String`

```
def func[T <% String](s: T) = s.substring(0,2)
```

Now, if I call that function with a `Double`, I'll get this

```
scala> func(9.123)
res8: String = 9.
```

And with a `Long`

```
scala> func(999999L)
res7: String = 99
```

But with an `Int`

```
scala> func(99)
<console>:15: error: No implicit view available from Int => String.
   func(99)
```

Your specific example

```
def func[T <% String](s: T) = s
```

doesn't *quite* work, though, since it actually returns `T` not `String`.  You can do this, though.

```
def func[T <% String](s: T): String = s
```